# How display Image using value from database in case of ms-Dropdown

Tags: jquery, msdropdown

I am using msDropdown for my image drop down menu. Each time user select an image, it will insert to database a value. Now I want when this page load, the drop down menu will populate the image selected base on the value currently store in database. But I really dont know how could msDropdown could understand and relate the value to the image.
Here is what I tried:

```
  $connector = new DbConnector();
  $Attend = mysql_query("SELECT `Attend` FROM `Database`.`Table` WHERE `Table`.`FieldName`='xyz'"); ?>
  <select name="Attend" id="Attend">
    <option value="'.$Attend.'" selected="selected">'.$Attend.'</option>;
    <option value="Yes" title="img/check.png"></option>
    <option value="No" title="img/no.png"></option>
  </select>
```

But it doesn't show the image when loading page.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a database and retrieving the picture is not a good option or not the way to go with displaying images rather you might go with CSS+Javascript or JQuery and display image using a simple     image tag

```
   Try some code like this, it might work out

function showPic(opt){

    var selopt = document.getElementById("opt").value;

    if(selopt == 1){
           document.getElementById("lambo").style.display="block";
    }
    if(selopt == 1){
           document.getElementById("audi").style.display="block";
    }
    if(selopt == 1){
           document.getElementById("ferr").style.display="block";
    }
}

<select id="opt" onChange="showPic;">
    <option value=1>Lamborgini</option>
    <option value=2>Audi</option>
    <option value=3>Ferrari</option>
</select>

<div id="lambo"> <img src="lamborgini.jpg" /></div>
<div id="audi"> <img src="audi.jpg" /></div>
<div id="ferr"> <img src="ferrari.jpg" /></div> `
```